# Is a falling leaf an example of a chaotic system?

Tags: aerodynamics, chaos-theory

Let´s assume is a wind still day in autumn. When a little change is made in the initial motion of a leaf at the time it falls off a tree, the resulting path of motion of the leaf is very different from the path that would develop if these changes wouldn´t have been made.

All the leafs though reach the ground within a maximum radius (wich is a function of the height of the tree) caused by chance effects. Can we, because we know that the leaves land within a certain area, still say that a falling leaf is a chaotic system? Or do we have to consider an infinite high tree, and consider the combined system of the air and the falling leave?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. With the qualification that chaos describes the behaviour of an ideal (continuous?) mathematical model, whereas leaves and the air through which they fall are real, I think it is a chaotic system.  Leaves falling from the same place but with a small change in orientation can land in very different places, and intermediate orientations do not necessarily land in between. As the difference in orientation is changed by smaller and smaller amounts (ad infinitum), the path of connected landing points becomes more convoluted.

I think that increasing the height of the tree will also increase the radius of landing sites on the ground, without limit.

Comment: It´s true that the radius of landing sites increases with the height of the tree, but the further you go (within the maximum radius), you will find fewer and fewer leaves per unit area, in accordance with the laws of chance. Wich is to say that the maximum radius is a function of height and thus predictable. So we can be sure that a leave will end up within the maximum radius. Isn´t this the same process as a lead ball that you give a velocity in a washing sink? No matter the velocity (of course it can´t be too big), the ball always ends up in the sink.

Comment: @descheleschilder : I think we agree that the maximum radius increases without limit.  The distribution of landing sites will be a 2D Normal probability distribution with the peak directly under the launch point.  Of course this distribution will "flatten" as the height is increased : the probability of landing within an area dxdy directly below the launch point will also decrease without limit.

Comment: @descheleschilder : The lead ball in the sink is constrained by the sink walls - no such constraint here.  The range of a projectile is constrained by launch speed, but in the analogy both increase without limit with the height of the tree.

Comment: Chaotic systems need not be ideal...

Comment: Can´t you say that the atmosphere is the constraint?

Comment: @descheleschilder : Not like the sink.  The atmosphere affects how much the leaves spread out, but I don't think it limits the radius as height increases.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your exact definition of chaos:

- We certainly have a **strong sensitivity to initial conditions** (butterfly effect), which is the one property of chaos everybody seems to agree upon.
- We do not have **topological mixing**.
- The falling to the ground is only a short-lived **transient** compared to the non-chaotic lying on the ground. So, at most, we have a chaotic transient.

To get something that is chaotic by all definitions (I am aware of), we would have to extend the system a little bit, for example:

- look at the entire tree;
- allow the tree to re-grow leaves;
- somehow deal with the leaves that reached the ground and letting their fate influence the system. For example, we could have a literal feedback process by having the rotting leaves act as a fertiliser that makes leaves on the respective side of the tree grow a tiny bit faster.

Comment: I think the OP is looking at the leaf falling through air as an abstract system.  So it does not require a tree, and the pile of fallen leaves does not have any influence.

Comment: @sammygerbil: I am aware of this. What I am trying to show is how the system from the question would have to be extended to get a system that is chaotic by all definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Chaos is typically phrased as a sensitivity to perturbation in initial conditions (amongst other important things things).  You can have a statistical distribution describing the final destination of leaves in general, when the path taken by any individual leaf is deemed chaotic.

As an example, consider common strange attractors.  Its easy to see that there is a statistical distribution in locations where a particle ends up, but predicting where any one particle ends up with any degree of accuracy is impossible after enough distance in orbit around a strange attractor.

Comment: What´s the connection between a strange attractor and this system?

Comment: @descheleschilder A strange atractor is a known chaotic system, and yet the position of the particle can be treated as a random variable with a probability density function.  The falling leaf also has a probability density function, with some limit as to how far the leaf falls from the tree. Thus, the mere presence of such a limit should not be construed as proof that the system is not chaotic, because there are known chaotic systems with that property.